# Contain fixed element within container

Tags: html, css

Having a flex layout with top, left, middle and right.
Middle is divided into *main* and foot.

Within the *main* I want to have fixed elements, kind of like an MDI, as well as static elements.

If one scroll the fixed element should stay in same position of view. But, it should be contained within the *main* element if it is moved above or to the left of *main*. As in: not overlap the top, left, right etc.

**THIS:**

<sup>*Colors and margins added to make a visual representation of the layout*</sup>

[image: Desired view]

**NOT THIS:**

[image: Undesired view]

Below is a simplified sample with a container within a container.

If one select the *fixed* positioning for the sub "window" it stay in place on scrolling, but it overlaps the parent if moved outside.

I can use absolute and reposition it on scroll by using JavaScript, but wondered if there was a pure CSS / layout way to get the same result.

```js
function set_style_pos (e) {
  moveable.style.position = e.target.value;
}
function halt (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
const drag = {
  el: null,
  ex: 0,
  ey: 0,
  xs: 0,
  ys: 0,
  move: function (e) {
    halt(e);
    drag.el.style.marginLeft = (e.clientX - drag.sx + drag.ex) + 'px';
    drag.el.style.marginTop = (e.clientY - drag.sy + drag.ey) + 'px';
  },
  end: function  (e) {
    halt(e);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', drag.end);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag.move);
  },
  start:  function (e) {
    let cs;
    halt(e);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', drag.end);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag.move);
    drag.el = e.target;
    cs = getComputedStyle(drag.el);
    drag.ex = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('margin-left')) || 0;
    drag.ey = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('margin-top')) || 0;
    drag.sx = e.clientX;
    drag.sy = e.clientY;
  },
  check: function (e) {
    let t = e.target;
    if (t.dataset.moveable == "1")
      drag.start(e);
  }
};
document.addEventListener('mousedown', drag.check);
document.addEventListener('change', set_style_pos);
lines.textContent = "scroll me\n".repeat(100);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #444;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: goldenrod;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 150px;
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
  cursor: move;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.box div {
  font-weight: 700;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box" id="moveable" data-moveable="1">
      <div>Move Me</div><br />
      <label><input type="radio" name="p" value="absolute" checked />absolute</label><br />
      <label><input type="radio" name="p" value="fixed" />fixed</label>
    </div>
    <pre id="lines"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to use CSS layers ? e.g.  the z-index property ? If its fixed it will become always the topmost window if there is nothing else defined. Its how fixed works. You will need a dark grey layer for the content. on layer above for the dialog. and on top a orange layer with the "window". And best of all this needs now also two custom scrollers :) I just hope thats woth it :)

Comment: @ThomasLudewig: Yes. I have done lots and lots of testing with z-index, moved it around had other containers rearanged and so on. But did not get there.

Comment: I think as long you do not use prooper designed z-index layers you will not get the desired result.From my expieriance and i play with this UI things since IE6... The main UI has to flly over all other things. The text and the dialog has to stand behind. That means z-index and position:fixed. As long as the main interface is not really flying over the Rest of the conten it will not work. And as mentioned - that will take some afford cause its the opposite what the "web guys" think a page should work. They love outmoving menues and so on. As a application developer i hate it..

Comment: BTW the z-index also works with negative numbers :) The standart value is "0". And we have also this nice RGBA thing now. You could come to the idea even to use a table and set the browser window cell to a background of 100% transparency.NOT recomanded but would work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `z-index`.

**Example:**

```js
function set_style_pos (e) {
  moveable.style.position = e.target.value;
}
function halt (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
const drag = {
  el: null,
  ex: 0,
  ey: 0,
  xs: 0,
  ys: 0,
  move: function (e) {
    halt(e);
    drag.el.style.marginLeft = (e.clientX - drag.sx + drag.ex) + 'px';
    drag.el.style.marginTop = (e.clientY - drag.sy + drag.ey) + 'px';
  },
  end: function  (e) {
    halt(e);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', drag.end);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag.move);
  },
  start:  function (e) {
    let cs;
    halt(e);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', drag.end);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag.move);
    drag.el = e.target;
    cs = getComputedStyle(drag.el);
    drag.ex = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('margin-left')) || 0;
    drag.ey = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('margin-top')) || 0;
    drag.sx = e.clientX;
    drag.sy = e.clientY;
  },
  check: function (e) {
    let t = e.target;
    if (t.dataset.moveable == "1")
      drag.start(e);
  }
};
document.addEventListener('mousedown', drag.check);
document.addEventListener('change', set_style_pos);
lines.textContent = "scroll me\n".repeat(100);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #444;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: goldenrod;
  /*flex-grow:1; Disable to control the height for presentaion*/
  height:200px !important;
  overflow:hidden; /*to hide scrollme lines*/
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 150px;
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
  cursor: move;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.box div {
  font-weight: 700;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.prevent{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  /*--The solution--*/
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box" id="moveable" data-moveable="1">
      <div>Move Me</div><br />
      <label><input type="radio" name="p" value="absolute" checked />absolute</label><br />
      <label><input type="radio" name="p" value="fixed" />fixed</label>
    </div>
    <pre id="lines"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="prevent">
  Prevent overlap
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using z-index before posting, but could not get it to work for this case.

Comment: @user3342816 It should work, Make sure to set a high `z-index` maybe like `1000`.

Comment: The problem is not to get it "high enough". The issue is to keep it in the main area, whilst not overlapping the other areas and being fixed - all due to hierarchy. Se pictures in post and my answer. If you can get that effect by using z-index alone I'd like to see it as I like to learn new solutions, but I have tried and did not manage to do it with z-index as is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sticky container and let children be absolute.

Had tested with `z-index`, all over, before posting but had not found any satisfactory solution that way.

I also tried various with `position: sticky`, and there is where I found the solution at last :)

One can wrap the sub windows in a sticky container which is positioned top left of the *main* container.

Pros:

- Simple
- Fairly clean HTML structure
- The window stay below scroll-bars of container
- Positioning relative to content wrapper

Cons:

- If one want to make it non-fixed / non-sticy one have to move the element to parent and vice versa.

Absolute positioned children will not expand the container – thus not rearranging the DOM flow. (Which was the issue on earlier attempts using `sticky`).

Tested in FireFox, Chrome, Vivaldi, Opera Mini and Opera.

The core of it:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="wrap-sticky">
            <div class="sub-window">
                Fixed Window
            </div>
        </div>
        Other "normal" content
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.wrap-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.sub-window {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```js
function get_pos (el) {
  let cs = getComputedStyle(el);
  return [
    parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('left')) || 0,
    parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('top')) || 0
  ];
}
function set_style_pos (e) {
  let [x, y] = get_pos (moveable);
  if (e.target.value == "sticky") {
    wrap_sticky.appendChild(moveable);
    moveable.style.left = (x - inner.scrollLeft) + 'px';
    moveable.style.top = (y - inner.scrollTop) + 'px';
  } else {
    inner.appendChild(moveable);
    moveable.style.left = (x + inner.scrollLeft) + 'px';
    moveable.style.top = (y + inner.scrollTop) + 'px';
  }
}
function halt (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
const drag = {
  el: null,
  ex: 0,
  ey: 0,
  xs: 0,
  ys: 0,
  move: function (e) {
    halt(e);
    drag.el.style.left = (e.clientX - drag.sx + drag.ex) + 'px';
    drag.el.style.top = (e.clientY - drag.sy + drag.ey) + 'px';
  },
  end: function  (e) {
    halt(e);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', drag.end);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag.move);
  },
  start:  function (e) {
    halt(e);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', drag.end);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag.move);
    drag.el = e.target;
    [drag.ex, drag.ey] = get_pos(drag.el);
    drag.sx = e.clientX;
    drag.sy = e.clientY;
  },
  check: function (e) {
    let t = e.target;
    if (t.dataset.moveable == "1")
      drag.start(e);
  }
};
document.addEventListener('mousedown', drag.check);
document.addEventListener('change', set_style_pos);
lines.textContent = "scroll me\n".repeat(100) + "horiz".repeat(100) + 'END';
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #444;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: goldenrod;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
  cursor: move;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.box div {
  font-weight: 700;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap-sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" id="inner">
    <div class="wrap-sticky" id="wrap_sticky">
      <div class="box" id="moveable" data-moveable="1">
        <div>Drag &amp; Move Me</div>
          <label><input type="radio" name="p" value="sticky" checked />In sticky</label><br />
          <label><input type="radio" name="p" value="absolute" />In main</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre id="lines"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE will also support it but you need some cross browser tricks. Not IE11 or edge but older versions need that as long you are not able to leave compatibility mode.